# How to find duplicates same column and print duplicates id in another column's?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I need to compare the value in a single column in a single table. Here is a sample table:

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/15nvaky.png]

Duplicates values id want print in column C.

In the above example  ID 1 and ID 6 are duplicates, So cell c2 want to print ID 6, like that c7 want print ID 1.

How to get ans for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can try below,

```
Sub test()

i = 2

With ActiveSheet
    For Each Cell In .Range("B2:" & .Range("B2").End(xlDown).Address)
        If Cell.Row + 1 < .Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row Then
            For Each C In .Range(.Cells(Cell.Row + 1, 2).Address, .Range("B2").End(xlDown).Address)
                If C.Value = Cell.Value Then
                    .Cells(i, 3).Value = C.Offset(0, -1).Value
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If there is multiple duplicates, Answer is comes in next row. Is it possible to change as next column ? if yes means how to do that ?

Comment: You would have to add another loop to loop around the "already duplicated"(Col C) list if found then put +1 column over else put at bottom of list